# Paypal IPN keeps failing - The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

We are using Woocommerce and Woocommerce Subscriptions. For some reason by default, Woocommerce Subscriptions (Reference Transactions) do not pass or include the Tax amount to Paypal. So I ended up modifying the class files and added in the field "TAXAMT" in the IPN.

However, when I did so, it is now giving us the error:

```
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
[L_ERRORCODE1] => 10004
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
[L_SHORTMESSAGE1] => Invalid Data
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
[L_LONGMESSAGE1] => This transaction cannot be processed.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[L_SEVERITYCODE1] => Error
```

**Can anybody please help me identify what's missing or what is wrong here?**
Below is the IPN request sent to paypal (via woocommerce paypal logs)

This is a recurring product. The product costs $7.70 and the Tax is $0.77 with a total of $8.47

```
[USER] => ****************
[PWD] => ****************
[SIGNATURE] => ********************************************************
[VERSION] => 124
[METHOD] => DoReferenceTransaction
[REFERENCEID] => B-4CR65046J0487452E
[BUTTONSOURCE] => WooThemes_Cart
[RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
[AMT] => 7.70
[CURRENCYCODE] => AUD
[INVNUM] => WC-5184
[PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
[NOTIFYURL] => https://affgo.co/go/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/
[CUSTOM] => {"order_id":5184,"order_key":"wc_order_56bad2660bf0f"}
[TAXAMT] => 0.77
[ITEMAMT] => 8.47
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Subscriptions → IMMag Monthly
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 7.70
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 7.70
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.77
```

Comment: That's not an IPN request. IPNs come to you, not from you to Paypal. I suggest the item tota;l should not include the tax, but this should all be answered in the documentation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your inputs! I thought so too but that was the term used by the Paypal Tech support person who's helping me with this as well.

Which one is the itemtotal? If you're referring to "ITEMAMT", I did try that as well, I set the value to 7.70 but still resulted to the same error.